# can't change Textview's background

Tags: android, timer, widget, textview

hi i have an clock widget here and i want it to change its background every 2 min but when i use

```
R.id.widget_textview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);
```

it says

```
Cannot invoke setBackgroundResource(int) on the primitive type int
```

and to change its background i need to loop with a variable i there and if condition , if 1 use pic 1, then wait 2 min if 2 use pic 2, and if 10 use pic 10 and i = 1 again. is there any ways better than this?

Answer (score 2):

Change your code as:

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget_textview);
textview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);
```

because R.id.widget_textview is id of textView

Comment: i got an error The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Widget how to fix this? thanks btw for answering its very useful

Comment: @user2033624 : try it as `TextView textview = (TextView)Current_Context.findViewById(R.id.widget_textview);`

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.widget_textview` is an int.

you will first need to do `findViewById(R.id.widget_textview)` to get the `View`.

Comment: i got an error The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Widget how to fix this? thanks btw for answering its very useful

Comment: Oh, if you are creating a widget you will need to use `RemoteViews`. Check this src code: https://github.com/Macarse/DuolingoWidget/blob/master/src/com/nasatrainedmonkeys/duolingowidget/service/WidgetUpdateService.java

Answer (score 0):

```
R.id.widget_textview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);
```

You can't do that. You have to do something like this:

```
TextView myTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widget_textview);
myTxt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);
```